# ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to run a script trough a cronjob. This is the matching line of the crontab:

```
@reboot sshpass -p (mypassword) ssh root@localhost -p 22 screen -d -m -L ~/bin/autorun.sh
```

And yes, I know that using the plain password is not secure at all, but I'd like to keep it like this.
I keep getting this error:
`ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`

This is the output of `service ssh status`:

```
Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-01-14 13:14:21 EST; 1min 13s ago
```

And this is the netstat output for Port 22:

```
root@vps65121:~# netstat -an | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0     64 158.69.212.156:22       95.88.113.40:58086      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12422
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     10422
```

I'm out of ideas. Also reinstalled ssh multiple times.

Comment: Connection refused means your remote ssh server is refusing the connection for some reason, I might be wrong, but I think is due to the fact that you are trying to connect as root and by default the server won't allow this. I'll check my comment and brb.

Comment: It could also be IP address conflict as I've seen here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30080/how-to-solve-connection-refused-errors-in-ssh-connection

Comment: @Alan In my sshd_config, I got "PermitRootLogin" set to "yes"

Comment: @Alan I'm connecting to localhost, so I guess this isnt the case

Comment: There are more steps needed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Your localhost ssh server must have root access enabled, then.

Comment: For which user is your cron job configured to?

Comment: @Alan I believe you didnt quite get my setup - I'm running a cronjob on my server that is meant to run the start.sh script at boot. The ssh server has root access enabled. My cron job is configured to the root user.

Comment: You could try restarting ssh server to see if it that's what it needs. Why ssh your own localhost, btw?

Comment: I did that like 1000 times already. I need to use ssh in order to start screen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an OS question and not a programming question. It may be more suitable for a different [se] site such as [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Comment: What exactly do you mean by start screen? Start an X window, a terminal within a window?

Comment: @Alan: The code in the question starts a GNU `screen` process.